# Problem not knowing QT += gui-private in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt6

When I enter this " QT += gui-private " in the *.pro for a project, the program gives the following error. I use Qt 6.0.1 GCC 10.3.1 in Ubuntu 20.04

```
-1: error: cannot find -lxkbcommon
-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
-1: error: [Makefile:321: untitled6] Error 1
```

Comment: You probably need to install `libxkbcommon-dev`

Comment: Thank you, error fixed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.